# DHTML menu not displaying

Tags: javascript, dhtml

I am trying to display the menu using DHTML, but I am getting a JavaScript error and menus are not getting displayed.

```
<script language="JavaScript" 
    vqp_datafile0="Welcome to Epicenter Fitness_files/epicenter_nav.js"
    vqp_uid0="61625" 
    vqptag="doc_level_settings">
    cdd__codebase = "Welcome to Epicenter Fitness_files/";
    cdd__codebase61625 = "Welcome to Epicenter Fitness_files/";
</script>

<script language="JavaScript"  
        src="Welcome to Epicenter Fitness_files/epicenter_nav.js" 
        vqptag="datafile"> 
</script>

<script language="JavaScript"  
        vqp_menuid="61625"  
        vqptag="placement">
    create_menu(61625)
</script>
```

When I looked in Firefox, it says that `create_menu` function is not found.

Is `create_menu` a built-in DHTML function?

My all JS files including `epicenter_nav.js` file(containing code to display menus and submenus) are saved under folder `D:\Welcome to Epicenter Fitness_files`.

Comment: Try to avoid spaces in directory names. Also, are you running this file from d: root? If not, try absolute paths.

Comment: I have tried absolute path and replaced the Spaces with %20. Both ways not working as well.

Answer (score 0):

Is this file located at the root of D:\? Because the path `"Welcome to Epicenter Fitness_files/epicenter_nav.js"` is relative to the current file.

Answer (score 0):

You server might not handle spaces in urls - try renaming your directory (and references) to Welcome_to_Epicenter_Fitness_files

**Edit:** also, this looks like the directory structure of a webpage saved with IE or Firefox (save as complete webpage). I'm not sure all JS is saved that way. Include files are definitely NOT saved, so double check your JS files contain the aforementioned function.